# c# regex referring to repeating named group

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing a regex to convert the following:

```
string input = @"
 {b sub}{b or}{b di}{b nate} def1...
 {b sub}{b tro}{b pi}{b cal} def2...
 {b su}{b per} def3...
 {b sum} def4...
 ";
```

into this:

```
'subordinate': def1...
'subtropical': def2...
'super': def3...
'sum': def4...
```

I.e., I need to remove '{b ' and '}' and decorate it, etc.

I'm not sure how to do it. I know how to match `{b }` but not how to match all of them and decorate it with quotes.

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\{b (?<Text>[^ }]+)})+", @"'${Text}'")
```

returns

```
 'nate' def1...
 'cal' def2...
 'per' def3...
 'sum' def4...
```

I.e., just last match within given instance ... . No idea how to refer to "all" groups of Text not just last group in given instance.

Sorry I can't even find what's the proper name for "the given instance" ... .

Comment: Can there be nested `{...}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, {} can't nest. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match the repeated substrings with `Regex.Replace` and then un-brace the separate braced substrings in the match evaluator part and format the whole match as you need.

Here is an example:

```
string input = @"{b sub}{b or}{b di}{b nate} def1...
{b sub}{b tro}{b pi}{b cal} def2...
{b su}{b per} def3...
{b sum} def4... ";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?:\{b\s+[^{}]*})+", m =>
            "'" + Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\{b\s+([^{}]*)}", "$1") + "':");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/CbncXI), output:

```
'subordinate': def1...
'subtropical': def2...
'super': def3...
'sum': def4...
```

The `(?:\{b\s+[^{}]*})+` expression matches 1 or more repetitions of `{b`, 1+ whitespaces and then 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}` up to and including `}`, and then, when the match is found, it is processed with `\{b\s+([^{}]*)}` regex that only matches 1 such sequence and captures the part after `b` + whitespaces and before `}` replacing it with the group 1 contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\{b (?<Text>[^}]+)\}` as the pattern and replace it with `${Text}` after you first replace `\{.*\}` with `'${0}':`.

Multiline, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  string input = @"
   {b sub}{b or}{b di}{b nate} def1...
   {b sub}{b tro}{b pi}{b cal} def2...
   {b su}{b per} def3...
   {b sum} def4...
   ";
  input = input.Replace("{b ", "").Replace("}", "");
  input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\n\s+(\w+)", @"\n'$1':");
```

Pattern explanation:

`\n\s+(\w+)` - match newline, one or mroe whitespaces, then match one or more word characters and store it in capturing group.